# Metabox Keeps Stripping Parts of Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, metabox

I am creating a custom metabox, and it will be filled with shortcode. The problem is, after I saved it, it keeps stripping / deleting the last part of the shortcode, like this:

Suppose to be:

> [myshortcode id="3"]

Result (error):

> [myshortcode id=

I checked the database, and it saved the way it suppose to be, and when I try on the front end, it works. I was going to leave it (at least for now) but if I save / update the page - again, then it will save the broken result.

Here is my code:

```
function custom_meta_box_markup($object)
{
global $post;
wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");

//retrieve the metadata values if they exist
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, "meta-box-text", true);

?>
    <div>
        <label for="meta-box-text">Text</label>
        <input name="meta-box-text" type="text" value="<?php wp_kses_post($value); ?>">

        <br>

    </div>
<?php  
}


function add_custom_meta_box()
{
add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Custom Meta Box", "custom_meta_box_markup", "product", "side", "high", null);
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");


function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{
if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
    return $post_id;

if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
    return $post_id;

if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return $post_id;

$slug = "product";
if($slug != $post->post_type)
    return $post_id;

$meta_box_text_value = "";

if(isset($_POST["meta-box-text"]))
{
    $meta_box_text_value = $_POST["meta-box-text"];
}   
update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-text", $meta_box_text_value);
}

add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);
```

Can anybody tell me what went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really should use [data sanitization](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) when updating postmeta. The issue is that WordPress is stripping double quotes as they're considered dangerous. You'll need to encode them, maybe by using [`wp_specialchars()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_specialchars).

Comment: I thought it was security issue, that's why I use wp_kses.. gonna try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: I could be mistaken but I believe `wp_kses()` should be used *on save* instead of when displaying the value.

Comment: Could be.. Anyway, wp_specialchars apparently deprecated.. lol. But it leads me to the correct answer, using esc_html >> working. But now I have a new problem, the shortcode is not running like it suppose to be and instead it display the "raw" code! lol Oh well, back to codecs

Comment: Are you using [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)? If you found an answer please add a description along with what you did to fix your issue in the answer box below so future readers with the same issue have a solution :)

Comment: I do and will do :)

Comment: `wp_kses()` is best on "save" if only because it is a very labor intensive function.

Answer (score 1):

I really should get some sleep :P The shortcode is [masterslider] and I manually wrote [metaslider].. That meta box must've gotten into my mind..

Just change the appropriate line to this:

```
value="<?php echo esc_html($value);  ?>">
```

and it works. Thanks @Howdy_McGee for pointing me to the right direction! Also @s_ha_dum for additional knowledge.